# How to access json data in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get `name` value. How do I access it?

json looks like this

[image]

```
    var result = null;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {

        result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

           for(var i = 0; i <= result.total_count; i++)
           {
               console.log(result.data[i].name);
           }
      }
    });
```

This is giving me result as I want but with an error

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in log.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON first:

```
const result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log(result.data[0].name);
```

The [responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) property you use returns the response as purely text. In this case you are trying to read the `data` property of a [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) object. Since this doesn't exist it will be undefined. Next you are trying to access the 0 property of an undefined value which will result in the error you encounter.

Using the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method will convert the string to a Javascript object which does have a data property.

Thanks @3limin4t0r for further clarifying in the comments!

Comment: `this.responseText.data[0].name` would try to access the `data` property of a string. String doesn't have a `data` property thus it returns `undefined`, accessing the property `0` of `undefined` will yield the error.

Comment: @3limin4t0r yes you are correct. It is not entirely correct to say a 'string cannot be used directly in Javascript'. I'll try and expand my answer.

Comment: @Mathyn My comment is nothing against your answer. I was just missing an explanation of why exactly this error occurred, so I thought I'd add it through the comments.

Comment: Still I think it better to explain why exactly this error occurred for future reference. Especially because strings are perfectly save to use in Javascript if used correctly.

Comment: Yes, its working but I am getting an error too `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @JamshaidAlam can you share what you code looks like right now?

Comment: @JamshaidAlam your for loop runs one iteration too long. Change `<=` to `<`

Comment: Ahh! error is gone. I realized I did `<=` it shoud be `< `

Answer (score -1):

This is demo json

```
{
    "name": "mkyong",
    "age": 30,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "88 8nd Street",
        "city": "New York"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "111 111-1111"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "222 222-2222"
        }
    ]
}
```

follow this code :

```
<script>
       var data = '{"name": "mkyong","age": 30,"address": {"streetAddress": "88 8nd Street","city": "New York"},"phoneNumber": [{"type": "home","number": "111 111-1111"},{"type": "fax","number": "222 222-2222"}]}';

    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    alert(json["name"]); //mkyong
    alert(json.name); //mkyong

    alert(json.address.streetAddress); //88 8nd Street
    alert(json["address"].city); //New York

    alert(json.phoneNumber[0].number); //111 111-1111
    alert(json.phoneNumber[1].type); //fax

    alert(json.phoneNumber.number); //undefined
</script>
```